# UISplitViewController portrait - popover problem in toolbar

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopover

I've take Apple's tutorial as example, and inserted in my iPhone app, to make it universal.
The popover shows a menu with 4 options, each a UIViewController.
If I select the 2nd, and then return to the first, the popover button, instead of staying in position 0 of the toolbar buttons, it goes a little more to the right.
If I go to the 2nd and back again, it goes more to the right.

What's wrong?

RL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all my ViewControllers are initialized in AppDelegate, i need to remove de barbutton each time i select a row in popover menu.
That way, when a VC is shown, the button goes in index 0, and does not go to the right in toolBar.

Thanks.

RL

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're pushing multiple things into the toolbar.items in your UISplitViewController delegate methods, or rather, you are adding more to toolbar.items in the "will show" delegate method, but you aren't removing all of them in your "will hide" method. If you post the code to your UISplitViewController delegate methods, we might be able to help more.